# Rename() function not working when attempting to add an extension to a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file-extension, file-rename

I have an extension-less file and I want to add an `.avi` extension to it. So I call this function after selecting the file via openfile dialog (I want to have the file opened after renaming):

```
int RenameVidAddExt(HWND hWnd, char oldname[MAX_PATH])
{
    int filenamesize=0, n=0;
    char extension [] = ".avi";
    char* newname;

    for (n=0 ; oldname[n]!=NULL ; n++)
    {
        filenamesize++;                                 
    }

    newname = new char[filenamesize+sizeof(extension)];

    newname = oldname;
    strcat (newname, extension);
    //SetDlgItemTextA(hWnd, IDC_EDIT1, szFile);     //test print of filenameof selected file
    //SetDlgItemTextA(hWnd, IDC_EDIT2, newname);    //test print of newname
    rename(oldname,newname);
    return 0;
}
```

The filename just doesn't change and I don't know why. Test prints show that both `oldname` and `newname` contain correct strings (old without extension and new with it).

Comment: `new[]` count: 1. `delete[]` count: 0. Uh oh.  Have you considered `std::vector`?

Comment: Did you check the errno? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f%28vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using C++, consider also using `std::string`:

```
int RenameVidAddExt(HWND hWnd, char oldname[MAX_PATH])
{
    char extension [] = ".avi";
    std::string newname = oldname;

    newname += extension;

    rename(oldname, newname.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Some side notes:

1. Remember, when you use `new` or `new[]`, you must use `delete` or `delete[]` later (when the object created with `new` or `new[]` is no longer needed).
2. When playing with strings, try and use `std::string` as much as possible. It will save you from having to handle memory manually, and they can be assigned / copied to other variables.
3. Rather than using `new[]`, it is often recommended to use `std::vector` instead. Resize the vector to the desired size. When you require a pointer to the first element, use `&vec[0]`. The benefit to using a `std::vector` is that memory management is done for you.
4. Don't calculate the length of strings manually, use a function like `strlen`. Alternatively, the length of a `std::string` can be obtained with `str.length()`.

Comment: Hi,
I know I have to delete[], I just didnt care about it when I realised the code is not working; I would simply add it in thenext step. 
I have never worked with std::string but it really seems to be better option now so I will rewrite the code. Thank you very much for brief explaining of the basics of std::string

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy a C-style string by assigning pointer values.  Your code dynamically creates a new buffer, then promptly orphans it by assigning to that pointer.

I suggest using std::string instead.  However, if you want to stay with the C-style strings,  try this:

```
newname = new char[filenamesize + sizeof(extension)];
strcpy(newname, oldname);   // Copies the original string character by character
strcat(newname, extension);
```

Good luck!

Comment: doesn't sizeof(extension) already include the null terminator?

Comment: @Pablo--whoops--you're right!  I was thinking it was a strlen, not a sizeof!  Correcting now...

Comment: Oh thanks, this worked. 
I have never worked with it so far but I agree, std::string would be better as I have read something about it now.